# How can I save the output of a detached screen with script?

Tags: logs, gnu-screen

I have a Python script `test.py` that only contains: `print('hi')`. I want to run it in a `screen` so that the output of the `screen` is saved by `script`.

I use the following command to run `test.py` in a `screen`, it works fine:

```
screen -dm bash -c 'python test.py'
```

However, I haven't managed yet to find a way to use `script` to save the output of the `screen`. How can I do it?

---

I unsuccessfully tried:

- `script -c  "screen -dm bash -c 'python test.py'" output.txt`: the output file output.txt doesn't contain `hi`, but only:

  ```
  Script started on Fri 26 Aug 2016 01:04:59 PM EDT

  Script done on Fri 26 Aug 2016 01:04:59 PM EDT
  ```

I use Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS x64.

---

Documentation:

https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html:

> -d -m: Start screen in detached mode. This creates a new session but doesn't attach to it. This is useful for system startup scripts.

http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_sh.htm :

> -c string: If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string. If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.

script's man page:

> -c, --command  run command rather than interactive shell

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should do it the other way round, run `script` inside `screen`:

```
screen -dm bash -c 'script -c "python test.py" output.txt'
```

Answer (score 17):

You can use the `-L` flag to create an automatic `screenlog.0` file

eg

```
$ screen -dm -L sh -c 'echo hello'
$ cat screenlog.0 
hello
```

If you have a long running screen session that isn't being logged then you can turn on logging later

eg

```
$ screen -dm -S test sh -c 'while [ 1 ]; do date; sleep 1; done'
```

Now we can turn on logging

```
$ screen -S test -p 0 -X log
```

Allow some time to pass, because the logging is written in blocks, and...

```
$ cat screenlog.0
Fri Aug 26 13:25:49 EDT 2016
Fri Aug 26 13:25:50 EDT 2016
Fri Aug 26 13:25:51 EDT 2016
Fri Aug 26 13:25:52 EDT 2016
Fri Aug 26 13:25:53 EDT 2016
Fri Aug 26 13:25:54 EDT 2016
Fri Aug 26 13:25:55 EDT 2016
Fri Aug 26 13:25:56 EDT 2016
Fri Aug 26 13:25:57 EDT 2016
Fri Aug 26 13:25:58 EDT 2016
```

Comment: Is their a way to save output history from begining when screen is already started without -L ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried the `screen -dm -L bash -c 'python running_4ever.py' ` and see the log as well as the newly created screen as detached, I wonder how do we attach to it or kill it? I tried `screen -r <screen_id>` to it but didn't work.

Comment: @Leo this sounds like you need to create a new question

Comment: @StephenHarris Hi Stephen, I figured it out. I tried `screen -dm -S <screen_name> -L bash -c "python running_4ever.py" ` and it worked, then I just used `screen -XS <screen_name> quit` to kill it. Thanks for the reply though

Comment: Don't know if it's just because I've started my `screen`s without naming the sessions, but I noticed that once logging is enabled for one (unnamed) screen session - eg. `screen -S ttys012.titanic -p 0 -X log` - then enabling it for another screen session sends the output to the same log file (and no, I'm not running the commands from the same working directory). Also, the command is a toggle, so to turn it off, you use the same command. Inside the screen, it'll show a message at the bottom whether it's enabling or disabling logging.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it is to attach the screen first:

`screen -r <pid or name>`

and then:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>

It will start logging into `screenlog.0`

Answer (score 0):

Could work!

```
screen sh -c './some-script 2>&1 | tee mylog.log'
```